# How to pass props to styled-component when using React.cloneElement

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a wrapper component and a number of nested components. I am passing a new prop `topMargin` to the nested components with `React.cloneElement` but `styled-components` seems to completely ignore them.

In the example I log props in `StyledInner` and `Inner`. The resulting props are quite different. What am I missing?

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-maxwell-hgkp1

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledOuter = styled('div')`
  background:blue;
  padding: 1rem;
`

const Outer = props => {

  const proppedChildren = React.Children.map(
    props.children, (child)=> 
    React.cloneElement(child, { topMargin: '10px'})
  )

  return <StyledOuter>{proppedChildren}</StyledOuter>

}

const StyledInner = styled('div')`
  background: red;
  margin-top: ${props => {
    console.log(props)
    return props.topMargin || '50px'
  }};
`

const Inner = props => {
  console.log(props)

  return <StyledInner>{props.children}</StyledInner>
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Outer>
        <Inner>
          This is where the magic happens.
        </Inner>
        <Inner>
          Here too.
        </Inner>
      </Outer>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Logging props results in the following:

On `<Inner />`

```
{
  children: "Here too.",
  topMargin: "10px"
}
```

On `<StyledInner />`

```
{
  children: "Here too.", 
  forwardedComponent: Object, 
  forwardedRef: null, 
  theme: Object
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Inner` component receives the topMargin prop, but then they doesn't pass the prop to `StyledInner`

```
const Inner = props => {
  console.log(props)
  return <StyledInner topMargin={props.topMargin}>{props.children}</StyledInner>
}
```

Comment: I'll admit to feeling really dim right now. Thank you.